# How to change the tab order of the controls in axapta?

Tags: axapta, x++

How to change the tab order of the controls in Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot control the tab order directly. The fields are tabbed in the field order given in the form. Use the `Skip` property to prevent tabbing into a field.

I guess you could use a [WinAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50236/how-do-you-programmatically-change-the-tab-order-in-a-win32-dialog) call to change the tab order, but it would be bad practice indeed.

Answer (score 3):

There is another way, using code in the init (or calling a method which handles the tabOrder from init).

```
void init()
{
    Array tabOrder = new Array(Types::Integer);
    ;
    super();

    tabOrder.value(1, Control1.id());
    tabOrder.value(2, Control2.id());
    tabOrder.value(3, Control3.id());
...etc

    element.tabOrder(tabOrder);
}
```