# MFC Tab order programmatically

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I was wondering is there a way to set the tab order at run time instead of design time? This is crucial as at initialisation some fields are being hidden or rearranged in the dialog.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Win32 API to achieve this:

```
SetWindowPos(hNewControl, hOldControl, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOSIZE);
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50236/how-do-you-programmatically-change-the-tab-order-in-a-win32-dialog) for more details.